# Angular CLI - Typescript throws: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I run in angular 4 project with ng serve and i get error

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

but I don't have any property length in my project..

the full error

```
    Your global Angular CLI version (1.2.1) is greater than your local
version (1.1.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15457:109)
    at parseSourceFileWorker (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15389:26)
    at Object.parseSourceFile (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15338:26)
    at Object.createSourceFile (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15192:29)
    at VirtualFileStats.getSourceFile (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:66:35)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.getSourceFile (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:213:38)
    at findSourceFile (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67909:29)
    at processImportedModules (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:68056:25)
    at findSourceFile (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67937:17)
    at processImportedModules (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:68056:25)
    at findSourceFile (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67937:17)
    at processSourceFile (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67840:27)
    at processRootFile (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67728:13)
    at E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67018:60
    at Object.forEach (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:1449:30)
    at Object.createProgram (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67018:16)
PS E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Angular 4\Youtube Channel Angular Firebase\full project of the instructor github\angular-firestarter-master>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "firestarter",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.67",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.1.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.4",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.4.3",
    "typescript": "=2.3.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is full stacktrace? `length` is used in a lot of modules. Maybe some of your dependencies are not correct

Comment: it make sense. it happen after i run npm install.. it full stacktrace I will update my post you can see

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: Yeah. Problem is definetely somewhere in dependencies. Could you also add your package.json content?

Comment: sure, i added it now

Comment: And problem start at which command? `npm install`? Are you doing something different before invoking it?

Comment: no. I just download github project from of angular 4 and run npm install. it looks like my angular/cli(1.2.1) isn't like in the package.json(1.1.3) but I changed it manually and still have the project

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong. It could be problem with your global dependencies vs project dependencies. It could be also a bug in the project.. I recommend you to contact with the author.

Comment: I run npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest and now I get "Cannot find module 'webpack-dev-server'"

Comment: So let's install it ;) `npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev`

Comment: that's what I did and then I get the error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: I had this as well. Some were due to typos or missing properties in json config files or unresolvable path in ///<reference path /> directives. The error message is useless :/ you just know somethings wrong

Answer (score 27):

You might be missing one or more files that typescript is trying to process. To find out which file you are missing just add

> console.log(fileName);

at the starting of the `createSourceFile` function at node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js file.

Comment: I saw that file is in my node modules, but error is still there.

Comment: I get a lot of files when I `console.log`, how can I know what is the missing file?

Comment: Nice! As the others noticed, it doesn't solve the problem but gives very useful hindisght: once I knew which file was missing, all I had to do was to search where it was imported and fix it from there.

Answer (score 12):

My error was caused by c&p error when creating a small component. I forgot to change path to component's template and styles.

Comment: Yeah same... I don't know why the error message isn't something like: *File old-file-name.html not found.* - would be a lot easier for developers.

Comment: In my case renamed template file but forgot to change it in the component

Comment: The most undescriptive error for something that seems like it would pretty common

Comment: Same here. I renamed one of my component, but I missed naming the selector, the template URL and stylesheet URL. I wish the error message were clearer

Answer (score 6):

Most likely you have changed around your modules in a way that needs the CLI to be restarted.

I had the same error running `ng serve` after removing a component from a module. By restarting that process and re running `ng serve` the error went away.

Comment: Good thing to check.  I refactored some components manually and forgot to make updates inside the component.ts file to match.  The error isn't terrifically helpful but as a rule of thumb, better suspect our own work before that of the community in most cases. :-)

Answer (score 6):

My problem was that, for some reason, my envioroment.ts file was missing. So check important files.

Comment: If you're using multiple envs, check that you didn't misspelled the one you're using too

Answer (score 2):

In my case I did the following and it solved the issue:

1. Create **environments** folder (if not exist) in **src** of the Project `C:\Users\abcd\Desktop\MyApp\src`
2. Put the two files **environment.ts** and **environment.prod.ts** in **environments** folder.

Answer (score 1):

Could be bad path to component templateUrl, perhaps missing the `./`

Before: `templateUrl: 'my-control.component.html',`

After: `templateUrl: './my-control.component.html',`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem (error during refactoring test).  All is good for angular v4.3.* and v4.4*

1. Change `@angular/cli`  version 1.7.3  to  **1.4.10**  in **package.json**   (latest for angular4)
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. `npm install --no-optional`

Answer (score 0):

Close the running port and Try rebuilding the app with "ng build"

Comment: Can you please answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66175657/how-to-solve-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-at-new-token

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's mysterious. But it won't hurt to offer what I had witnessed and maybe a bit history. None or maybe some historical event might have caused it but I really don't know.

- Everything is good. Angular 8 running inside `18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)LXC` within `19.10 ubuntu host` with npm `6.14.2`, node`10.16.3`
- Upgraded host to `20.04 LTS(Focal Fossa)`. Write some code. Remove a package called `angular-shepherd`. Try to build --prod. This errors shows up during angular Generating ES5 bundles.
- Tried everything. All failed.
- Reset what I did inside the project. Still fail.
- Reboot LXC.
- Fixed.