# ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - Angular 2.0 Unit Testing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am able to successfully run the test application with "ng test" but whenever I'm making any change at run time to the test file I'm end up getting below error. I have tried couple of solutions mentioned in below links but no luck. Please help me to resolve this issue.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "testing-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.6.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "puppeteer": "^1.0.0",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.5.3"
  }
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5053

[Angular CLI - Typescript throws: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219750/angular-cli-typescript-throws-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)

Pasting entire error for the reference -

```
ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (C:\testing-demo\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescri
pt.js:8982:109)
    at parseSourceFileWorker (C:\testing-demo\node_modules\typescript\lib\typ
escript.js:8941:26)
    at Object.parseSourceFile (C:\testing-demo\node_modules\typescript\lib\ty
pescript.js:8900:26)
    at Object.createSourceFile (C:\testing-demo\node_modules\typescript\lib\t
ypescript.js:8728:29)
    at new TypeScriptFileRefactor (C:\testing-demo\node_modules\@ngtools\webp
ack\src\refactor.js:79:35)
    at Object.findLazyRoutes (C:\testing-demo\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\s
rc\lazy_routes.js:18:22)
    at AotPlugin._findLazyRoutesInAst (C:\testing-demo\node_modules\@ngtools\
webpack\src\plugin.js:216:50)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\testing-demo
\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:494:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Comment: Can you create minimal reproduction on github?

Comment: I am not sure how to create it on github. But I will share the configuration files if needed.

Comment: At least add information about `@ngtools\webpack` and `typescript` versions

Comment: added in the question

Comment: You use too old version of typescript

Comment: Can you suggest which one I should use?

Comment: For `@angular/cli@^1.6.7` I would bump up angular version to 5 and typescript at least to 2.5.3. You can install @angular/cli globally and run `ng new proj` and then compare version you will need

Comment: tried with suggested version change but no luck :(

Comment: You need to remove node_modules and packages.lock files and then run npm i

Comment: yes I did that -> rm -r node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install

Comment: package.lock file?

Comment: yes removed that files as well

Comment: Add your changed package.json to question

Comment: added in the question

Comment: You didn't update angular and I see two versions of @angular/cli

Comment: you are pointing to this right? "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",

Comment: Should I change it to 5.0.0?